# A variable is reset after some time

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

There's an int variable accessed via singleton pattern.

But the problem is that the variable is set once and it's reset to 0 after some time.

It seems to be reset by garbage collection. Saving the value in Activity.onSaveInstanceState and restoring it in onCreate() is non-working.

Is the solution to save the variable in disk?

I just want to prevent it from resetting.

Comment: Can you please show how the variable is used, and more specifically, if possible, when it is deleted?

Comment: The GC should only free variables when they have no active reference.

Answer (score 1):

The variable will only stay active as long as the application is active. Android is notorious for killing background processes automatically. Unfortunately, if you're trying to access a variable that you'd like to persist over multiple runs of the application, you *will* need to write it to disk somehow.

There are a couple of options open to you, however. I will list the ones [Google recommends](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

- [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), "Store private primitive data in key-value pairs."
- [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), "Store private data on the device memory."
- [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), "Store public data on the shared external storage."
- [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db), "Store structured data in a private database."
- [Network Connection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw), "Store data on the web with your own network server."

  Of all of these solutions, [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), is probably the easiest to implement. It is as simple as:

  ```
  public class Calc extends Activity {
      public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
         super.onCreate(state);
          . . .

         // Restore preferences
         SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
         boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
         setSilent(silent);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onStop(){
          super.onStop();

        // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
        // All objects are from android.context.Context
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
      }
  }
  ```

Code is from the [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to prevent it from resetting.

You can use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save and then retrieve the variable later. A tutorial on how to do so can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

On a side note though, are you sure your variable is resetting because of garbage collection?